# handle server timeout in passportjs

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook

I follow the code sample given in Passport js page .

```
app.get('/fbconnect', function (req, res) {
var loadingMessage = "Connecting to Facebook. Please Wait";
res.render('index', { title : 'Home', message : DEFAULT_MESSAGE, loadingMessage : loadingMessage, loadingDivDisplay : "block"}, function(err, html) {
    if (!err) {
        passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ['email', 'publish_actions'] })(req, res);
    }
});
```

});

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', function (req, res) {
var loadingMessage = "Processing the request. Please wait",
    isAuthenticationError = false;
if(req.query && req.query.error){
    req.session.authError = req.query.error;
    req.session.authErrorReason = req.query.error_reason;
    isAuthenticationError = true;
}
res.render('index', { title : 'Home', message : DEFAULT_MESSAGE, loadingMessage : loadingMessage, loadingDivDisplay : "block"}, function(err, html){
    if (isAuthenticationError === true) {
        res.redirect('/');
    } else {
        console.log("into right place");
        passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/authorisationComplete'})(req, res);
    }
});
```

});

But I face some my own server issues, which takes a long time and then displays gateway timeout issue after authentication.

I am trying to display a message (like "Processing the request. Please wait")from my server instantly after authentication from FB, while takes the 2 minute time to reach the gateway timeout .

But failing . Can someone help in this

Answer (score 0):

That is handled via Connect's [session](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) middleware, so for example:

```
.use(connect.session({ secret: 'mysecretkey', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))
```

Is it what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render, when you provide a callback, you have to make sure that the html string is rendered.

ie..

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('test.html', function (err, html) {
    res.end(html);  // explicitly sending the html response to the client
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

will render the response . But

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('test.html', function (err, html) {
    // this is equivalent to what you have . No explicit response. You should try adding a res.end(here) here
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

wont.